# UI5 - How to Resize Table Height

Tags: javascript, css, sapui5

​Hello,

It seems that table row height of UI5 Table is pretty big with lot of white space above and below the text.

[image]

Is there anyway I can resize the height of the row with lesser px? I want to apply this seeting only for this table and not all tables.

When I look at its CSS in Chrome Developer tools, I get following:

[image]

`element.style{height: 49px}` is the culprit. How can I make it like 30 px and can apply only to this table?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the looks of it I believe you are using the sap.ui.table.Table. You can use the [rowHeight](https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.table.Table.html#setRowHeight) property of the control to reduce the row height.

Answer (score 1):

Try using **sapUiSizeCompact** style in your page or your table. You cannot set exact height with this one but it might be enough for your case.

```
class="sapUiSizeCompact"
```